# Not getting event from smart contract on ethers.js

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I have contract this part is simply creating smart contract for NFT. At the end of the createToken() I am emitting event.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT OR Apache-2.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    address contractAddress;
    event ItemCreated(
        uint256 indexed tokenId
    );

    constructor(address marketplaceAddress) ERC721("Metaverse Tokens", "METT") {
        contractAddress = marketplaceAddress;
    }

    function createToken(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint) {
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();

        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true);
        emit ItemCreated(newItemId);
        
    }
}
```

I am trying to read event ItemCreated on ethers.js

```
        const web3Model = new Web3Modal()
        const connection = await web3Model.connect()
        const provider  = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
        const signer = provider.getSigner()

        let contract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, signer)
        let transaction = await contract.createToken(url)
        let tx = await transaction.wait()

        console.log('tx' ,tx)
        let event = tx.events[0]
        console.log('event', event)
```

Unfortunately, the response is not giving me any event
Please see below response. evens property is empty

```
{
    "to": "0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512",
    "from": "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266",
    "contractAddress": null,
    "transactionIndex": 0,
    "gasUsed": {
        "type": "BigNumber",
        "hex": "0x5858"
    },
    "logsBloom": "0x0000000000000...",
    "blockHash": "0xe66248c22832b34776c6720a6bec19bf20e9ba9af4a63ff25bd0f0689f19f037",
    "transactionHash": "0xc6de2da6186ca972cc69efa265c7da5e6d780a0c25d4ad849aa4be4be9cac501",
    "logs": [],
    "blockNumber": 1,
    "confirmations": 1,
    "cumulativeGasUsed": {
        "type": "BigNumber",
        "hex": "0x5858"
    },
    "effectiveGasPrice": {
        "type": "BigNumber",
        "hex": "0x8d8f9fc0"
    },
    "status": 1,
    "type": 2,
    "byzantium": true,
    "events": []
}
```

events are empty
I am sure event is emitted as I checked in hardhat-tracker

```
 npx hardhat test --logs                   


  NFT market
[Receiver] Transfer(from=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, to=[Sender], tokenId=1)
[Receiver] ApprovalForAll(owner=[Sender], operator=0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3, approved=true)
[Receiver] ItemCreated(tokenId=1)
[Receiver] Transfer(from=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, to=[Sender], tokenId=2)
[Receiver] ApprovalForAll(owner=[Sender], operator=0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3, approved=true)
[Receiver] ItemCreated(tokenId=2)
```

Any idea what I am dong wrong?
Below link to the repo https://github.com/Filip-Konkowski/Polygon-nft-market

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have selected the correct network in your metamask? The same thing happened to me once :D Also, be sure to deploy using the network parameter such as `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
let event = tx.events[0]
console.log('event', event)
```

with all the functions you have called before your emit command there could be other events. try

```
tx.events[tx.events.length - 1]
```

that should give you the last event